# IBM Worklight - Is it possible to add UINavigationController as the starting native page?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to integrate a navigation based iOS application into IBM worklight. However, I am not able to add `UINavigationController` as its first native page. In the tutorials, they have only explained integrating a normal `UIViewController`. Since `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, Shouldn't one be able to integrate that as well?. Could some one please tell me if I can integrate a `navigationcontroller` using **"WL.NativePage.show"** API.
  Currently, I am not able to figure out how to set the `rootviewcontroller` for the `navigationcontroller` object.

Comment: Same here. Hopefully @idan-adar could help us.

Comment: I'll see about this tomorrow unless someone comments until then, but do note that this has got nothing to do with the WL.NativePage.show API method; this method simply and only transitions you to the native page, but this native page can be whatever you want. That part is purely native. Make sure that if adding a UINavigationController, you're not missing anything that is there when adding a UIViewController (I am not an iOS developer).

Comment: @IdanAdar  Any update on this. We are also trying the same thing.

Comment: @vishal_g, see this blog post: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/integrating_a_worklight_based_ios_app_with_xcode_storyboard?lang=en_kr

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the motives for your request so this might not answer your question, but it does offer an alternative.

---

See the following blog post by Anton Aleksandrov. In it Anton explains how use native controls, which can also be navigation controls in your case, in your Worklight Hybrid application. That is, w/out the need to do it in a "native page".

Essentially, you are still using the HTML file as the "starting page" of the application, but you shrink the Cordova WebView, allowing you to add, place, native controls at the top and bottom for example. There you can place a native navigation control.

Blog post: [[iOS] Combining native and web controls in Cordova based applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/ios_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en)